# how to call css asset pipeline in grails

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

i already install asset-pipeline:1.8.10.

i'm confusing how to call css and javascript. i already googling. i found [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHDBlGtAHB4)

but i havenot understood.

at folder grails-app/asset/stylesheets have based.css,bootstrap.css, main.css. last i create new file with application.css

but i only add this code to application.css

```
/*
*require bootstrap
*require based
*main.css
*require jquery-ui.custom
*require bootstrap
*require_self
*require_tree
*/
```

in gsp i  use `<asset:stylesheet src="application.css" />`

but it likes not work. because the page is blank.

example :
grails-app/asset/stylesheets have based.css
based.css coding is

```
body
{
   #FF0000;
}
```

at index.gsp

i call `<asset:stylesheet src="application.css" />`

then how about application's content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a couple of things wrong in your application.css, first why do you import bootstrap twice? the second thing is, that you use require_tree with no folder given like: "require_tree . " or "require_tree subfolder"

here should be a working example:

```
/*
*require bootstrap
*require_tree .
*/
```

with a given folder structure like:

```
/grails-app/assets/stylesheets/
  /application.css
  /based.css
  /main.css
```

and the bootstrap plugin required via BuildConfig.groovy. 
The other aproach is to require different stuff directly instead of using the require_tree directive:

```
/*
*require bootstrap
*require based
*require main
*/
```